# Fill out Winform using gridview when I press edit button

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to fill out all form (form 1) fields when the `GridView` row is highlighted and press edit button on another form (form 2). I want to use `gridview.focus();`. Is this possible?

Comment: What code do you have at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. Just grab the data in the selected row and add it to you edit form as required. Pass it into the constructor of the form or have a public load function. Opening the form will give it focus.